# Ext.data.JsonStore getCount() returns 0 records web service

Tags: .net, web-services, sencha-touch, extjs, jsonstore

I am working on a Sencha Touch application, and can't get data from my web service.

The following code worked for another user on [sencha's forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?74361-Solved-JsonStore-and-asp.net-web-service/page4),page 4.  I've modified it to match my web services output json.

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        id: 'Agents',
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'ws/Service.asmx/GetAgents'
            ,method: 'post'
            ,jsonData: {}
            ,headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8;'}
            ,reader:{root:'d', record:'rows'}
        }),
        totalProperty: 'd.totalRows',
        idProperty: 'AgentID',
        fields: ['AgentID', 'FirstName','LastName'],
        autoLoad:'true',
        listeners: {
                beforeload: function(myStore, options) {
                    console.log('beforeload: myStore.count = ' + myStore.getCount());
                    console.log(options);
                },
                load: function(myStore, records, options) {
                    console.log('load: ' + myStore.getCount());
                    console.log(records)
                    console.log(options);
                },
                exception: function(misc) {
                    console.log('exception:');
                    console.log(misc);
                }
            }
});
```

Firebug Console Output:

```
beforeload: myStore.count = 0
load: 0
[]
true
```

Firebug confirms the JSON returned from 'ws/Service.asmx/GetAgents' is:

```
{"d":{"success":true,"totalRows":2,"rows":[{"AgentID":1,"FirstName":"Jelena","LastName":"Akerhus"},{"AgentID":2,"FirstName":"Londo","LastName":"Molari"}]}}
```

However, when I type 'myStore.getCount()' into the console I get 0 records.

Here is the part of the code for Service.asmx:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true, XmlSerializeString = false)]
    public object GetAgents()
    {
        List<Agent> agents = new List<Agent>();
        agents.Add( new Agent(1, "Jelena", "Akerhus") );
        agents.Add( new Agent(2, "Londo", "Molari") );

        object data = new { success = true, totalRows = agents.Count, rows = agents };
        return data;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, I registered the model separately, but with data types.  I use a store with a JsonReader, I removed some of the extra things you've added in.  Hope this works for you...

```
      Ext.regModel('Agent', {
        idProperty:'AgentID',
        fields: [{name:'AgentID', type:'int'},{name:'FirstName', type:'string'},{name:'LastName', type:'string'}]
      });

      var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        model  : 'Agent',
        proxy: 
        {
           type:'ajax',
           url:'test.json',
           reader:{
             type:'json',
             root:'d.rows',
             totalProperty: 'd.totalRows'
           }
        },
        autoLoad:'true'
      });

      var list = new Ext.List({
        fullscreen: true,
        itemTpl : '{FirstName} {LastName}',
        store: store
      });
      list.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added the changes you suggested, but am still getting 0 from myStore.getCount(). I'll update the question to reflect your suggestions and some of the things I've been trying.

Comment: When I have these problems, I use the debuggable, non-minified, commented version of sencha.  In this case search for JsonStore, and set some break points in the read methods, step through and may see what's not right in your config.

Comment: This worked! I had to add the headers 'Content-Type' back because it's necessary for my web service to return the data properly.